# Help understanding Localization

Tags: algebraic-geometry, localization

[Page 707 of Dummit and Foote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6zNn.jpg)I am having trouble understanding the argument to prove the universal property of localization.

Quoting Dummit and Foote page 707, $ \Phi(\frac{x}{1})= \phi(x) $ and this implies uniqueness.

Can someone explain why that this is the case?

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: Needs context. Not all of us have a copy of D&F in front of us.

Comment: attached a picture

Answer (score 1):

Proving uniqueness of functions (including homomorphisms) fulfilling some specific property is usually done by taking two such, and proving that they are equal.

So say we have two homomorphisms $\Psi_1, \Psi_2:D^{-1}R\to S$ with the property that $\Psi_1\circ\pi = \Psi_2\circ\pi = \psi$. It is clear that on any element of the form $\frac x1\in D^{-1}S$, we have $\Psi_1(x/1) = \Psi_2(x/1)$, because by the property they share, they must both equal $\psi(x)$. At the same time, we must have $\Psi_1(1/d)= \Psi_2(1/d)$ for any $d\in D$, as they must both equal $\psi(d)^{-1}$. Finally, for a general element $\frac xd\in D^{-1}R$, we have $\Psi_1(x/d) = \Psi_2(x/d)$ because $\frac{x}{d} = \frac x1\cdot \frac1d$, and $\Psi_1, \Psi_2$ are both ring homomorphisms. Thus we have $\Psi_1 = \Psi_2$.

Comment: But what if they were only equal at the point $$ \frac{x}{d} $$ and take other values at other points?

Comment: @RSquared The point is that the above proves that they're equal on _each_ element of $D^{-1}R$ that may be written as $\frac xd$ for some $x\in R, d\in D$. Every element of $D^{-1}R$ may be written that way, so they're equal everywhere.

Comment: Can you make the 2nd line a bit clearer? Doesn't it automatically give $$ 
\Psi_1 = \Psi_2 $$?

Comment: Why did we assume that?

Comment: Oh. I got it! Thank you.